# Variation of Fermat number, looking for literature on special properties

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, tetration

Suppose we define a recursive function as follows:

$F_k(0) = 1$

For $i \epsilon \mathbb{N}, i>0$, we define:

$F_k(i) = k^{F_k(i-1)}$

So if $k=2$ we get:

$F_2(3) = 2^{2^2}$

$F_2(4) = 2^{{2^2}^2}$

I want to know what such numbers are called, and if there are generalizations of it. Thanks.

Comment: In keeping with my Answer I've added the tag [tag:tetration] to your Question.  By clicking on that you can find other posts on the same subject and read the tag wiki for a bit of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a variety of *notations* have been introduced for this, many authors refer to this "iterated exponentiation" as [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Knuth in particular favors an "up-arrow" notation that lends itself to [powerful generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) of the idea.

[Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) $3\uparrow^n 3$ arose in connection with a problem in [Ramsey theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory), so there are definitely "combinatorial applications of it".

Comment: Thanks!
I noticed that there are no combinatorial applications of it. I was interested in this due to the fact that if I have a bit string of size 1, the number of combinations of this are 2 (0,1). If I take these strings and combine them in all possible ways I get 2^2 possibilities. If I take those strings and repeat the process, I get 2^2^2 combinations. Repeating this procedure i times yields 2|| i

Comment: You might find the article on [Ackermann's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) relevant.